# how to find controls in custom window in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I designed a form template for Window , and named "WindowStyle1":

```
<Style x:Key="WindowStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowTextBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
                <Border Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Background="#FF27C986" Margin="10">
                    <Border.Effect>
                        <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0" Direction="180" Opacity="0.52" BlurRadius="10"/>
                    </Border.Effect>
                    <Grid Loaded="OnWindowLoaded">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="94"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="38"/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.RowSpan="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                            <AdornerDecorator>
                                <ContentPresenter/>
                            </AdornerDecorator>
                        </Border>
                        <Button Click="minimize_window" x:Name="btn_window_minimize" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4.565,9.5,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="20" Height="19.96" Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyle_Windows_MinimumSize}" BorderThickness="1"/>
                        <Button Click="maximize_window" x:Name="btn_window_maximize" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="34.565,9.5,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="20" Height="19.96" Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyle_Windows_MaximumSize}"/>
                        <Button Click="close_window" x:Name="btn_window_close" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="64,9.5,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="20" Height="19.96" Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyle_Windows_Close}"/>
                        <Grid MouseLeftButtonDown="Window_MouseLeftButtonDown" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="38" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="#FF27C986">
                            <Label Name="lbl_title" Content="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0.998,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="20" Foreground="White"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="ResizeMode" Value="CanResizeWithGrip">
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource WindowTemplateKey}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

and i bind this .xaml file to "Window.cs" class :

```
namespace WpfApplication2
{
    partial class Window : ResourceDictionary
    {
        public Windows()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

but i can't find button controls in my "MainWindow.xaml".
**main question :** 
how to find label control that defined in custom window style in wpf

Any Idea?
Excuse me for poor English!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do it in the Loaded event (or later).

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var label = Template.FindName("lbl_title", this) as Label;
        Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
    }

    void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var label = Template.FindName("lbl_title", this) as Label;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
this.GetTemplateChild("minimize_window");
```

You can find out more about this method [here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.gettemplatechild%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Templates in WPF have a self-contained namescope. This is because templates are re-used, and any name defined in a template cannot remain unique when multiple instances of a control each instantiate its template.

Answer (score 0):

You can find elements that have been defined in a `ControlTemplate` by using the [`FrameworkTemplate.FindName` Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworktemplate.findname(v=vs.110).aspx), which *Finds the element associated with the specified name defined within this template*.

You can see the full story in the [How to: Find ControlTemplate-Generated Elements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613586(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN, but here is a short example taken from the linked page to give you an idea:

```
// Finding the grid that is generated by the ControlTemplate of the Button
Grid gridInTemplate = (Grid)myButton1.Template.FindName("grid", myButton1);
// Do something to the ControlTemplate-generated grid
MessageBox.Show("The actual width of the grid in the ControlTemplate: "
    + gridInTemplate.GetValue(Grid.ActualWidthProperty).ToString());
```